# Python Selenium Infinite Scroll - re scraping

Tags: python, selenium

I've built a script that uses selenium, it works well, however the site I am scraping infinitely loads, and so built in something to manage this.

However every-time it scrolls down it re scrapes the data it scraped before!

How can I change the script to it only scrapes data that hasn't been scraped yet?

I have seen some questions similar to this, and added the some code based on them, however I think my case is slightly different!

Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import os
import csv

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/chromedriver")
browser.get("***url***")

filename ="fileName.csv"
f = open(filename, 'w')
headers ="Title, Date, Time\n "
f.write(headers)

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('').click()
time.sleep(3)
page = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('')

# Get scroll height
last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

t_end = time.time() + 60
while time.time() < t_end:
    try:

        for items in page:

            title = items.find_element_by_class_name('').text.replace(',', '|')
            date = items.find_element_by_class_name('').text

            print('Name:',title)
            print('Date:',date)
            print("")

            f.write(title + "," + date.split(" ")[0] + "," + date.split(" ")[1] + "\n")

            # Scroll down to bottom
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(5)
        page = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('')

    except:

        break

f.close()

browser.quit()
```

Comment: Can you share the link?  I think I have a solution but I need to test it on something.

Comment: why can't you all the way down until all the pages loaded and then scrap it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample that will take care of the scrolling until all the dynamic rows are loaded and then scrape the page. Make sure to add `import time`

```
driver.get("https://anilist.co/user/Agusmaris/animelist/Completed")
time.sleep(3)
footer =driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.footer")
preY =0
while footer.rect['y']!=preY:
    preY = footer.rect['y']
    footer.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    time.sleep(1)
print(str(driver.page_source))
```